# Can pylint receive options other than enable and disable in python source?

Tags: python, pylint

Like options in: http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#id28

For example: the option of 'good-names'

We can't use #pylint good-names:var

Comment: You can set options in the `pylintrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, this doesn't work. IIRC, indeed only enable/disable work in python source code (for now).

Answer (score 0):

No but if you're happy to use [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8), lines that contain a `# noqa` comment at the end will not issue warnings